# Android productFlavors in gradle-kotlin-dsl

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I've experimented gradle-kotlin-dsl in an android project. I'm managed to make it work, but I'm stuck in how to define `productFlavors`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion(Config.Android.compileSdkVersion)
    buildToolsVersion(Config.Android.buildToolsVersion)

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(Config.Android.minSdkVersion)
        targetSdkVersion(Config.Android.targetSdkVersion)
        versionCode = Config.Version.code
        versionName = Config.Version.name
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions("dimension")

    productFlavors {
        //product flavors here
    }
}
```

After some investigation I've got the solution, just use the `create` method:

```
productFlavors {
    create("flavor1") {
        //flavor configurations here
    }
    create("flavor2") {
        //flavor configurations here
    }
}
```

Comment: you should show what you have attempted to do so far.  nobody will guess on your behalf

Comment: @AmitVaghela Why did you remove the gradle tags? From the few words in the question I'd assume its both gradle and gradle-kotlin-dsl related

Comment: add your build.gradle

Comment: Thank you for your reply @msrd0 and Yuliwee,
After weekend investigation I've got the solution

Answer (score 18):

After some investigation I've got the solution, just use the create method, adding here in case someone need it:

```
productFlavors {
   create("flavor1") {
        //flavor configurations here
    }
    create("flavor2") {
        //flavor configurations here
    }
}
```

Comment: So, how can I do in multi module project?