flavorDimensions, Multiple errors with direct copy+paste from Android themselves
I directly copied and pasted a code snippet into my app level build.gradle.kts file. The snippet was from an up-to-date Android Studio tutorial. When I tried to sync my Gradle files, I got multiple errors and their only solution was to ask Google Gemini. I'm using the Canary version of Koala. I even gave in and looked at Gemini's solution, and it was the exact same thing that I had pasted before, so no help there. The errors and code snippet are below.
Code Snippet:
flavorDimensions "app_type"
    productFlavors {
        demo {
            dimension "app_type"
        }
        full {
            dimension "app_type"
        }
    }

Errors:
e: file:///C:/Users/REDACTED/AndroidStudioProjects/ExprackExpenseTracker6/app/build.gradle.kts:10:22: Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
>> Ask Gemini Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

e: file:///C:/Users/REDACTED/AndroidStudioProjects/ExprackExpenseTracker6/app/build.gradle.kts:13:23: Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
>> Ask Gemini Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

e: file:///C:/Users/REDACTED/AndroidStudioProjects/ExprackExpenseTracker6/app/build.gradle.kts:16:23: Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
>> Ask Gemini Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

e: file:///C:/Users/REDACTED/AndroidStudioProjects/ExprackExpenseTracker6/app/build.gradle.kts:12:9: Unresolved reference: demo
e: file:///C:/Users/REDACTED/AndroidStudioProjects/ExprackExpenseTracker6/app/build.gradle.kts:13:13: Unresolved reference: dimension
e: file:///C:/Users/REDACTED/AndroidStudioProjects/ExprackExpenseTracker6/app/build.gradle.kts:15:9: Unresolved reference: full
e: file:///C:/Users/REDACTED/AndroidStudioProjects/ExprackExpenseTracker6/app/build.gradle.kts:16:13: Unresolved reference: dimension


The linked tutorial uses build.gradle file not build.gradle.kts that is a different format. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/48123240/150978

Thank you for letting me know about that. I never would've spotted that error without you. I found the proper code for build.gradle.kts, and it is working now. Thank you!
